# C++ vector of classes error

Tags: c++, class, function, vector, polymorphism

I got this

```
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

class A{
     protected:
         int test;
     public:
         void test(){} 
};
class B : public class A{
    public:
        void test2(){}
};

int main(){
     vector <A> new_vector;
     A a1;
     new_vector.push_back(a1);
     B b1;
     new_vector.push_back(b1);

     new_vector[0].test();
     //THE PROBLEM IS HOW DO I DO THIS:
     new_vector[1].test2();
```

}

logically is possible but it gives me an error, how I do it in the right way?

In python I do something like that all the time in a very easy way, it is possible in c++?

Comment: BTW, You are having object slice issue.

Comment: On that note, there's nothing polymorphic about this either.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that the vector only includes space for an `A` object, there's no way to fit a `B` in there.

For polymorphism, you need a pointer, reference, or smart pointer.  To help with lifetime management the latter is suggested.

```
std::vector<std::unique_ptr<A>> new_vector;
new_vector.emplace_back(new A());
new_vector.emplace_back(new B());
```

then you can use `dynamic_cast` on elements to discover whether there really is a `B` and call `B` specific members.

However, using virtual member functions for polymorphic behavior is much more efficient than `dynamic_cast`.

Comment: I wrote what you said and I've got this: "Symbol 'unique_ptr' could not be resolved" I am currently using eclipse and linux c++ compiler

Answer (score 0):

You can do this the same way that python does it, by not storing the objects directly into the vector and instead using a pointer/reference to the actual objects themselves.

```
#include <memory>
typedef std::vector<std::unique_ptr<A>> AVector;
```

Polymorphism is allowed in this case, you can push a pointer to anything derived from A.

In the case you were trying to attempt, you were trying to fit round pegs into square holes. A std::vector actually is actually a simple wrapper around code that allocates a big block of memory members * sizeof(T).

"unique_ptr" is a C++11 container for a pointer, that knows to delete it when it goes away. If you don't have C++11/C++0x support, you could either use a pointer or make your own "auto" pointer wrapper.

```
// Old-style pointer
typedef std::vector<A*> AVector;
AVector avec;

avec.push_back(new A);
avec.push_back(new B);
avec.push_back(new A);
avec.push_back(new B);

// now it's your responsibility to 'delete' these allocations when you remove them.
void discardAvec(size_t position) {
    A* ptr = avec[position];
    delete ptr;
    avec.erase(avec.begin() + position);
}
```

See live demo of the walk-thru below [at ideone.com](http://ideone.com/lo1G7I):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <vector>

typedef std::vector<class A*> AVector;

class A
{
protected: // so B can access it.
    int m_i;
public:
    A(int i_) : m_i(i_)
    {
        std::cout << "CTor'd A(i) " << (void*)this
                  << " with " << m_i << std::endl;
    }
    A(int i_, bool) : m_i(i_)
    {
        std::cout << "CTor'd A(i, b) " << (void*)this
                  << " with " << m_i << std::endl;

    }

    virtual ~A()
    {
        std::cout << "DTor'd A " << (void*)this << " with " << m_i << std::endl;
    }
};

class B : public A
{
    int m_j;
public:
    B(int i_, int j_) : A(i_, true), m_j(j_)
    {
        std::cout << "CTor'd B(i, j) " << (void*)this
                  << " with " << m_i << ", " << m_j << std::endl;
    }

    virtual ~B()
    {
        std::cout << "DTor'd B " << (void*)this
                  << " with " << m_i << ", " << m_j << std::endl;
    }
};

int main()
{
    AVector avec;

    std::cout << "create A(1)" << std::endl;
    avec.push_back(new A(1)); // allocated an "A" on the heap.
    std::cout << "create B(2, 1)" << std::endl;
    avec.push_back(new B(2, 1)); // allocated a "B" on the heap.
    std::cout << "create B(2, 2)" << std::endl;
    avec.push_back(new B(2, 2));
    std::cout << "create A(3) " << std::endl;
    avec.push_back(new A(3));
    std::cout << "populated avec" << std::endl;

    A* ptr = avec[2]; // take the pointer of what is actually a B
    avec.erase(avec.begin() + 2); // remove it from the vector.
    std::cout << "removed entry 2 from the vector" << std::endl;
    // 'ptr' is still valid because it's an allocation, and C++ doesn't
    // garbage collect heap allocations. We have to 'delete' it ourselves.
    // Also note that because A and B have virtual destructors,
    // you will see both of them called.
    delete ptr;

    // Now watch what DOESN'T happen as we exit.
    // everything we CTOR'd that doesn't get DTORd is a leak.
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I wrote what you said and I've got this: "Symbol 'unique_ptr' could not be resolved" I am currently using eclipse and linux c++ compiler

Comment: It needs `#include <memory>` and C++0x or C++11 support. If you don't have those, then you can instead use just a traditional pointer, but then you have to make sure that you `delete` the objects later. See e.g. I added to the answer

Comment: Added a fully fleshed out demo.